# Reconnect Hazelcast (smart) client to CP subsystem

Tags: hazelcast, raft

I am connecting to a HZ cluster as a smart client. After the client is running successfully for xome time I encounter `com.hazelcast.cp.exception.CPGroupDestroyedException`.

In this case I'd like the client to forget about the old CP subsystem and just reconnect as if it was the first time I called [getCPSubsystem](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#getCPSubsystem--). What is the preferred way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A CPSubsystemException which is thrown when a request is sent to a destroyed CP group.

"Forget about the old CP Subsystem." Well there are a couple ways of resolving this but both are brutal. You can use the Blue/Green feature to black list the old cluster or you can shutdown the client instance (forces all sockets to close).

As for recommended we would recommend not changing the CP Subsystem even though I can certainly understand why you would want to change it. The advantage of the smart client is long lived sockets vs using a proxy; however, this does put more importance on the client use of a circuit breaker.

Hope this helps,